# No footnotes are produced

Tags: footnotes

I cannot see footnote in my document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%       
   }
   \makeatother
\usepackage[stable,perpage]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\section{a\footnote{b}}
\newpage
\section{c}
\end{document}
```

Why is it so and how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is twofold. The usual solution that works in most cases, that is,

```
\section[Title]{Title\footnote{Footnote}}
```

doesn't work because you apply `\MakeUppercase` to your section titles. Adding `\protect` in front of `\footnote` solves the immediate problem of typesetting the footnote, but its text will be in small caps.

The technically correct solution is

```
\section[Title]{Title\protect\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{Footnote}
```

The optional argument *must* be used in such cases or the footnote mark will appear in unexpected places as soon as you enable headers or try producing the table of contents. The `\protect` is necessary to avoid `\MakeUppercase` doing nasty things to it.

The stylistically correct solution is, as others have commented, *not using footnotes to section titles under any circumstances*.

---

I notice that you're using the obsolete `pslatex` package. Replace it by `mathptmx`.

Answer (score 10):

You need to `\protect` the command try this:

```
\section{a\protect\footnote{b}}
```

I am not too sure if this is a good idea though, having footnotes in headings (they will also appear in the TOC). A footnote, normally is an explanatory note and headings should give a clear message of the text that follows. A footnote in a heading means your heading is not explanatory on its own.

Comment: At the very least, the optional argument to `\section` should be used.

Comment: @jon Leaving aside the technicalities, one needs to revise the section text to be self explanatory. If need be to start the section with some explanatory material.

Comment: Another good reason for *not* having footnotes in the argument of the `\section` command is that -- at least with the current definition of the `\section` command -- the contents of a footnote will be typeset in all-uppercase even if the `\footnote` command is `\protect`ed.

Comment: @Mico Not too sure about your statement. It worked when I tried it out and capitalized it.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: With the OP's definition of the `\section` command, the entire argument of the command -- including any (protected) footnotes -- is rendered in all-uppercase. I can't imagine that this is what the OP would want. Moral of the story: Don't use `\footnote`s in the argument of sectioning commands...

Comment: While I agree with the sentiments, I think it is best to encourage (only) avoiding footnotes in section titles, but to provide a solution (if there is one) to the problem that is asked.  For all we know, the OP is asking on behalf of someone else who simply doesn't care about a solution that involves rewriting his/her masterpiece.

Comment: @jon I did exactly that and no more. I provided a solution to the OP's exact question, provided a warning regarding the TOC and expressed my views regarding footnotes in headings. How do you know that the OP's friend did not want footnotes in the TOC also? There are also possible issues with hyperref:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides -- Indeed; I was referring more to your comment to my comment.  But really, no matter: I agree with your answer.  I just thought mention of the optional argument would make your answer more complete.